# Changing keywords to highlight in an RMarkdown document

Tags: css, r, rstudio, r-markdown

I have been writing a document in `bookdown` where within the *.Rmd file I call a figure by using the following syntax

```
\@ref(fig:MyFigureName)
```

This differs slightly from the notation that you would use in a normal RMarkdown file exporting to latex which would be

```
\ref{fig:MyFigureName}
```

The issue I am running into is that when I write something in bookdown the function calling the Figure is not being highlighted properly (see image below).

I have imported my own rsTheme (which is from my understanding, basically a .css file) but I don't see an option to add keywords to highlight.

[image: Actual Look]

But I would like for the entire function to be colored differently from the inline text (Photoshop version of desired output shown below)

[image: Desired Look]

Does anyone know how I would edit my *rsTheme file in order to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that an editor problem and not an Rmarkdown/bookdown problem? The editor needs to know the specific rules of what to highlight.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @ekstroem, are you suggesting I use different tags? Although I'm not sure of the answer (which is why I posted the question) I would assume the answer would be related to the rsTheme file (which is what I edited)

Comment: My comment was mostly that it was an editor issue and not something that was related to R og R-markdown (but certainly RStudio). Maybe ut's possible to provide an update to RStudio that defines the code highlighting